# How to deploy django project and runtime environment with all in once click

Tags: python, django, deployment

On Windows, its like WAMP, but it including your project code.

Your Project + Django + Python + (other dependence models) + Apache + MySQL all in one installation.

anyone know this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout), that does these things. I haven't used it with Django, but see no reason why it shouldn't work for Django as well (and bcchuns link, see below, shows that it does, as expected). I use it for Plone (with nginx and varnish, typically).

Comment: This tutorial should be helpful: http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/